# How to Import Multiple CSV Files into ONE MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I have a child table:

```
create table Battery(
Battery_Number primary key, 
Pack_Position, 
Pack_Number, 
Assembly_ID, 
foreign key (Pack_Number) references Pack(Pack_Number), 
foreign key (Assembly_ID) references Assembly (Assembly_ID)
);
```

And two Parent tables:

```
create table Pack(Pack_Number primary key, ...);
create table Assembly(Assembly_ID primary key auto_increment,...);
```

The relationships are one to many for each parent-child relationship. One Pack contains many batteries, one Assembly has (produces) many batteries.

Now, I have been using LOAD DATA INFILE and two separate .csv files to fill in the Pack and Assembly tables, respectively.

I am asking if there is any way to fill in Battery table with these two .csv files that I have used for the parent tables. These two .csv files contain all the data needed in the Battery table.

Battery Number is from one .csv, and Pack Position and Pack Number are contained in the other .csv, while Assembly_ID is auto-incremented. I am asking for guidance to fill in the Table Battery, but I am stumped with the fact that I need data from both excel csv sheets AND the foreign keys.

Thanks!

Comment: does the csv file have an id, sky, key whatever for the Assembly items?

Comment: The Assembly csv file only contains the data filled into the table. Such as timestamp, mass, weight, etc. And in LOAD DATA INFILE for Assembly table I SET Assembly_ID = Null; to automatically set the Assembly ID key accordingly

Comment: how do you expect to match battery and assembly latter if you use no keys?

Comment: do you suggest I add a batterySN column in Assembly table and use an if statement such that if Battery.BatterySN = Assembly.BatterySN then set assembly_ID = 1, etc?

Comment: Im sorry, It would not be an if statement but it would be:
set assembly_ID = Assembly.Assembly_ID where battery.BatterySN = Assembly.BatterySN

Comment: if in the input files you don't have a way of match assembly and battery, there is not much you can do... do you have a way of match the input files (this is includes if you were going to match them manually one by one in excel), what is it?

Comment: I thought about this as a backup: the original csv file has battery assemblies by row. So by row it shows the raw materials that went into each 5 battery so at the end of each row there is battery 1, battery 2, battery 3, battery 4, battery 5, in their respective columns. In MySQL Assembly table, I originally ignored this as a column and used @dummy over the battery columns to load the rest of the data. What I am thinking now is to add each of the 5 columns to the table, add the battery numbers in the table along with the data, and that could act as the connection between the two. Is this ok?

Comment: no, there is no need for that.. use only the original excel file for imports, first import the battery... then import all the assemblys (and discard duplicated), in the 3rd round populate the connection table between assemblys and battery (this means you need one extra table).

Comment: I think I understand. Are you suggesting I treat the relationship like a many-to-many (although realistically it is not)? Thus, I should remove the Assembly_ID foreign key from the Battery table, then add a third table that loads both the Assembly_ID and Battery_Number? Thanks again

Comment: do you reuse the assemblys across the baterrys? if you do, you need the connection table, if you don't you can put the baterry_id on the assembly table during the second round of the data importing...

Comment: If I am reading your question correctly, yes. Each assembly creates 5 batteries, so I do reuse the assemblys across the batterys. Thank you